# Sorting table data with JQuery, table has columns with dates and dollar signs, which plug-in is good?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, gridview-sorting

I have to sort a table and looking for right plugin. Some of the columns have dates and some have currency signs($) as shown below. Are there any JQuery plugins available for sorting this kind of data.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There an excellent/cleverly named plugin for this called "tablesorter" :), check it out here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/